# migrate drupal 7 multi site from acquia dev server to live server

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, acquia

What i have done:

I have installed acquia dev. I created new subdomain named abc

I could access the site url as http://abc.localhost:8082 in my local server.

I could see the folders within folder sites as

- sites/all
- sites/default
- sites/abc.localhost

I have uploaded the files to my server and exported local database to import to live database.

My questions:

How to access abc.localhost site from the live server now and how to change configurations?

Anyone out there to help me in this. I could explain further for any comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Web mastering, belongs http://webmaster.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Typically, your Drupal multi site structure should be as follow

```
sites/all
sites/default
sites/example.com
sites/sub.example.com
sites/example2.com etc...
```

the URL abc.localhost is a local URL only, so for the live server, you would need to change the directory title to your live server's domain name as seen above.

You could also do the following if you need to regularly update code between your live and local versions

```
sites/all
sites/default
sites/example.com -> abc.localhost // You can use a symlink here
sites/abc.localhost
```

Comment: what would be the access url?? like in local server, abc.localhost is access as http://abc.localhost:8082 (using Aquia Dev). I have uploaded files to http://myserver.com/demo (demo folder).

Comment: @yajay The 'access url' will be whatever you've set it up as in your web server config